# How is harmonic motion (specific and not a special case) different from periodic motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, definition, oscillators

I have seen written in many books that a motion that repeats itself after a specific time period follows periodic or harmonic motion.
However I know for a fact that damped harmonic motion cannot repeat the initial motion (parameters defining motion like amplitude, velocity etc. change).This clearly shows that harmonic motion does not repeat itself. How can I clearly differentiate it as a separate entity?

I am probably messing myself with the meaning of the words.

Comment: @RogerVadim i wanted a clear demarcation between the three given motions periodic, oscillatory and harmonic. As there are many examples which shows all three motions are different.

Comment: @kraansgard there is a discussion in the comments to my answer to the quoted question: no clear demarcation exists: harmonic implies linear force, periodic reproduces after a period, oscillatory is periodic oscillations - where the object retraces its path (more  apendulum than a planet), but the term is broadly applied to motions that are not strictly periodic.

Comment: @Roger Vadim you have explained the difference between oscillatory and periodic motions pretty well,however I wanted a difference for harmonic motion too.

Comment: I also explained it: *harmonic* means a linear restoring force, $F=-kx$, which leads to solutions in terms of sines and cosines. E.g., if $F=-kx^3$, and the equation is $m\ddot{x}+kx^3=0$, the motion is still oscillatory and periodic, but not harmonic.

Comment: @ Roger Vadim so essentially sine or cosine values refer to a harmonic motion.

Comment: Indeed. Incidentally, sine and cosine are an example of what is called in math *harmonic functions*. I expanded my quoted answer to include our discussion.

Comment: @ Roger Vadim thanks for broadening my horizon on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

"Periodic" means a motion or a signal that repeats.

"Harmonic" means the motion follows a sine or cosine curve, for example $x = A\sin \omega t$.

"Damped harmonic" means the motion follows a sine or cosine curve multiplied by a function that decays to zero, for example $x = Ae^{-bt}\sin \omega t$ where $b$ is a positive constant.

Harmonic motion is periodic, but damped harmonic motion is not.

Here are some periodic signals (electrcardiograms) that are *not* harmonic. Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Normal_12_lead_EKG.jpg/1280px-Normal_12_lead_EKG.jpg).

[image]

Comment: By harmonic do you mean shm or as a whole harmonic motion. If it is harmonic as a whole is this how we differentiate it so that it has a niche meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a semantic issue. A "damped harmonic oscillator" does not mean the overall motion of the particle is simple harmonic. Rather, it refers to an originally simple harmonic oscillator that is somehow exposed to a damping force, leading to its motion being affected.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic motion is a special kind of period motion, in that it is "pure". One way to quantify that is to say that the acceleration is always proportional to the displacement, or:

$$\frac {d^2} {dt^2}\big(x(t)\big) =\lambda x(t) $$

So it is an eigenfunction of the operator $\frac {d^2} {dt^2}$, with eigenvalue:

$$ \lambda = -\omega^2 $$

With that you can define basis functions:

$$|\omega\rangle = e^{i\omega t}$$

so that any motion, $g(t)$, can be projected onto them:

$$ g(t) = \langle g|\omega\rangle=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \tilde g(\omega)e^{i\omega t}dt$$

And now all the information about the motion is contained in the (complex) amplitudes versus frequency, $\tilde g(\omega)$.

It's a very useful way to thing about periodic motion.

With damping, you find that the frequency becomes complex:

$$ \omega'=\omega + i\xi $$

which is another useful way to look at damped harmonic motion.

Comment: I sort of get it but are all motions representable as some some combination of shms?

Comment: @JEB so the condition to define any harmonic motion lies in its basic form of shm.

Comment: @Buraian Yes, that's what a Fourier transform is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Etymology_of_the_term_"harmonic"  Harmonic has come to mean "solution of Laplace eq", which in free-space is sines and cosines, or equivalently $\exp(i\ldots)$. But the idea of a motion that is an eigenfunction of some wave-equation operator is important. It's the whole reason we talk about "frequency" in the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to say that the period decreases as the amplitude decreases, since the oscillating object has less distance to travel in one cycle. The damping force, however, reduces the speed to exactly counteract this effect. Thus the period and frequency of a damped oscillator are constant throughout its motion.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.