# Is period of an oscillatory motion constant?

Tags: oscillators

suppose a body is moving back and forth about a mean position in irregular intervals of time. Is this motion is an oscillation or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are all oscillatory motions periodic motions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632100/)

Comment: As explained in the answer linked above, *oscillations* is not a well-defined term. In principle it means periodic motion (i.e., motion with a constant period), but in practice the term applied to cases that are not really periodic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in physics “oscillation” is reserved for periodic motion, while what you described is closer to “fluctuation”. However words are just words and the usage will depend on discipline, subject, researcher.